# Using DateTime.TryParseExact to verify XML Schema dateTime compliance

Tags: c#, datetime, xsd

I am trying to verify that a C# string is compliant with XML Schema dateTime format. Looking at the MSDN, it seems like "o", "s", or "u" standard format strings could all describe valid dateTimes, but I can't get DateTime.ParseExact to work for me. What am I doing wrong here?

```
string myDate = "1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-04:00";
DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

None of the above work. Sorry if my formatting is bad: first time posting a question here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you want to test that the data is XML compliant, you could use the [`XmlConvert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todatetime.aspx) method:

```
DateTime dt = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(myDate);
```

This will throw a `FormatException` if the given string does not have the correct format.

Answer (score 9):

Just use [`XmlConvert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todatetime.aspx) (note that `XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string)` is considered obsolete now and you should use [`XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162342.aspx).

However, if you insist on using `DateTime.ParseExact` (and there are good reasons to do so but then you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to avoid exception throwing in cases of fail) you can use the following format string:

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz";
```

The parentheticals in the above paragraphs might be cumbersome to parse (I have a habit of doing that; sorry).